# Can't read audio CD in Linux, and I getting Sense errors in syslog

Tags: ubuntu, compact-disc, scsi

Using Ubuntu 12.10, I get this awkward error when I try to play a CD. Here is what dmesg shows when I try to play an Audio CD with `vlc /dev/sr0`

```
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 128
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 128
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 128
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  
Add. Sense: Illegal mode for this track
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
```

I am running this on a Lenovo X230 with the Ultrabase Series 3 w/ Optical Drive. Here is the result of a `uname -a`,

> Linux x200s-ssd 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here is the result of `lshw` for the CD-ROM drive,

```
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVDRAM GU40N
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom4
         logical name: /dev/cdrom5
         logical name: /dev/cdrw4
         logical name: /dev/cdrw5
         logical name: /dev/dvd4
         logical name: /dev/dvd5
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw4
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw5
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: QX20
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom4
```

Comment: Looks to me like your DVD drive is a bit stuffed.  Can you read regular disks ?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин how do I remedy the problem described -- ie., can't read audio cd.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to play an **audio** cd through the command line using vlc, you need to use

`cdda`

VLC uses this protocol (or access module) to read data from a device or network. Usage: cdda://device@track

The module name to use at the command line is cdda, but you can also use cddasimple.

For Ubuntu, use  `vlc cdda:///dev/sr0`